# kotlin - compare and combine key and values of Hashmap

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have 2 Hashmap

```
hashMap1 : HashMap<String, MutableList<String>> = {ab=["hello", "how", "are", "you"], cd=["my", "world"], ef = ["life", "is", "nice"]}
hashMap2 : HashMap<String, MutableList<String>> = {ab=["how", "you", "in", "life"], ef = ["nice", "to"], gd = ["fun"]}
```

I would like to compare both the Hashmap keys and values(List of string) and create a new map with the values that map

In the above 2 map, if I compare the keys ->  ab and ef match. Values in ab -> "how", "you" and ef -> "nice" match
Hence my new map should be

```
hashMap3 = {ab=["how", "you"], ef = ["nice"]}
```

How do I get this output ?

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: Please add valid kotlin code for your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing by the input and output of your description, I created this test case which applies to your example:

```
@Test
fun `should return map with key-value pairs of only matching value strings`() {
    val hashMap1 = hashMapOf(
        "ab" to listOf("hello", "how", "are", "you"),
        "cd" to listOf("my", "world"),
        "ef" to listOf("life", "is", "nice")
    )
    val hashMap2 = hashMapOf(
        "ab" to listOf("how", "you", "in", "life"),
        "ef" to listOf("nice", "to"),
        "gd" to listOf("fun")
    )

    val result = hashMap1
            .filter { (key, _) -> hashMap2.containsKey(key) }
            .mapValues { (key, value) -> hashMap2.getValue(key).filter { it in value } }
            .filter { (_, value) -> value.isNotEmpty() }

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(
        hashMapOf(
            "ab" to listOf("how", "you"),
            "ef" to listOf("nice")
        )
    )
}
```